# How to make Opacity only apply to background in div class

Tags: css, class, html, opacity

When I set the opacity to my main-body div class, it makes the text and everything else opacity too. I only want the gray background to have opacity.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="main1">
content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main1
{
background-color:#333333;
border:2px solid #7C7C7C;
text-align:center;
width:1250px;
top:auto;
bottom:auto;
left:300px;
right:300px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Everything gets opacity when this happens. Any help?

Comment: please upload full code to fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the background color an opacity

```
background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
```

Comment: Please note the browser compatibility of this method: http://caniuse.com/css3-colors

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 divs inside that with the same size as each other and make them over lap then you make div 1 have opacity and div2 have the content. I would attach an example but in using my phone

Answer (score 0):

```
background-color:rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5)
```

in case your BG gonna be a color you can use alpha filter which is 0.5 in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color to rgba(r,g,b,opacity)

background-color: (51, 51, 51, 0.2).

This will put opacity on only the background, and not the entire div (which included your text
)

You can use a [converter](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm) to convert hex colors to rgb colors.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to color the text!! First like others said use CSS background color. Here's the full code and the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/J2BRD/1/)

```
.main1
 {
 background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
 border:2px solid #7C7C7C;
 text-align:center;
 width:150px;
 top:auto;
 bottom:auto;
 left:300px;
 right:300px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 color: black;
```

}

HTML

```
<div class="main1">
content
</div>
```